# У меня выходит такая ошибка. Можете помочь в чем проблема?

Tags: android, xml, android-navigation-drawer

// Мой TAG =

```
     11-15 17:04:06.097 10484-10484/com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok/com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                              at com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                              at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:176)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070062
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1981)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:208)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppComp
```

//Мой activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

// Мой nav_header_main =

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/food" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Ресторан - Уголок"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="retorane_ugolok@gmail.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

// Мой  app_bar_main =

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

// Мой content_main =

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.md.nurkan.cafeugolok.activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewCafe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `app:srcCompat` на `android:src`

Answer (score 1):

`app:srcCompat` используется, если Вы хотите поддерживать vector картинки для preAPI 21.

Добавив в **gradle:**

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
}
```

---

Для того, чтобы понять ситуацию и правильно обеспечить поддержку векторных изображений во всех API, советую изучить следующую блок-схему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]